# SQL with nested select only returns one row when several should be shown

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have the following sql:

```
SELECT          
            ROUND(SUM(MS.score) / count(P.module_id),2) AS average_score,
            (SELECT Count(MS.phase_id) FROM Module_score MS WHERE MS.phase_id = P.id) as attempts,
            (SELECT ROUND(Count(MS.phase_id)/ (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM User_has_Team WHERE Team_id = 1) *100,2) FROM Module_score MS WHERE phase_id = P.id) as percent_completed
            FROM
              Module_score MS
                 LEFT JOIN
            `Phase` P ON P.module_id = MS.module_id
                JOIN User U on U.id = MS.user_id
            WHERE
             P.academy_id = 1 AND P.team_id = 1 AND P.start < now()
```

This returns the following:

```
# id, average_score, attempts, percent_completed
 '89',   '3.94',         '2',      '100.00'
```

Now this is fine however it should return all of the phases that are before `now()`

Which is the following:

**Phase table**

```
'89', '1', '1', '1', '2014-07-08 00:00:00', '1', 'none', '22:22', 'none', '1'
'90', '1', '1', '1', '2014-07-22 00:00:00', '2', 'none', 'none', 'none', '1'
'91', '3', '1', '1', '2014-07-08 00:00:00', '3', 'gege', '123451', 'Marc Rasmussen', '0'
'92', '1', '1', '1', '2013-02-15 00:00:00', '4', 'none', 'none', 'none', '1'
```

I have tried alot of different approaches but without luck

Can anyone push me in the right direction or explain to me why it is happening?

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the backtick "quoting"

Comment: Based on your data I can only guess that you only have an user that is linked with the data you shown. And based on your data from phase table the user_id column would be the sixth. Is that right ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Actually the id is only to show that only 1 row is being processed the idea is that the average_score, attempts and percentage should be based on all on the phases and not just 1 single phase

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(MS.score) / count(P.module_id),2) AS average_score,
-------------^ --------------^
       (SELECT Count(MS.phase_id) FROM Module_score MS WHERE MS.phase_id = P.id) as attempts,
       (SELECT ROUND(Count(MS.phase_id)/ (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM User_has_Team WHERE Team_id = 1) *100,2) FROM Module_score MS WHERE phase_id = P.id) as percent_completed
FROM Module_score MS LEFT JOIN
     `Phase` P
     ON P.module_id = MS.module_id JOIN
     User U on U.id = MS.user_id
WHERE P.academy_id = 1 AND P.team_id = 1 AND P.start < now();
```

These turn the query into an aggregation query.  Without a `group by`, such a query returns exactly one row.  In most versions of SQL, this query would return an error, because you are correlating the subqueries using `p.id`, but that is not part of a `group by` clause.  MySQL allows this through a `group by` extension.  I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT p.id,
       ROUND(SUM(MS.score) / count(P.module_id),2) AS average_score,
       (SELECT Count(MS.phase_id) FROM Module_score MS WHERE MS.phase_id = P.id) as attempts,
       (SELECT ROUND(Count(MS.phase_id)/ (SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM User_has_Team WHERE Team_id = 1) *100,2) FROM Module_score MS WHERE phase_id = P.id) as percent_completed
FROM Module_score MS LEFT JOIN
     `Phase` P
     ON P.module_id = MS.module_id JOIN
     User U on U.id = MS.user_id
WHERE P.academy_id = 1 AND P.team_id = 1 AND P.start < now()
GROUP BY p.id;
```

This may do what you want.  The correlated subqueries seem quite complicated, so I suspect they can be simplified.  However, it is unclear what results you actually want.